# error migrate from vaadin 23.3.5 to vaadin 24.0.1

Tags: vaadin

```
maven.compiler.source: 17
vaadin.version: 24.0.1
quarkus.version: 2.16.0.Final
```

ERROR [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/annotation/WebFilter
at io.quarkus.undertow.deployment.UndertowBuildStep.(UndertowBuildStep.java:141)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
at io.quarkus.deployment.util.ServiceUtil.classesNamedIn(ServiceUtil.java:29)
at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader.loadStepsFrom(ExtensionLoader.java:215)
at io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor.run(QuarkusAugmentor.java:107)
at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:331)
at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:252)
at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:60)
at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.firstStart(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:86)
at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:447)
at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:59)
at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInCl(CuratedApplication.java:149)
at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInAugmentClassLoader(CuratedApplication.java:104)
at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:131)
at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:62)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:516)
at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:466)
... 16 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vaadin 24 uses Jakarta EE 10 which means that it requires Quarkus 3.

Comment: Jakarta 10* editing requires 6 or more letters..

Comment: Thanks for the notice. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks!!I still have another problem

Comment: maven.compiler.source: 17
vaadin.version: 24.0.0
quarkus.version: 3.0.0.Alpha6

fixed the previous bug, now when npm install runs all node_modules are 
created in the project, but when mvn quarkus:dev runs it deletes me 
the node_modules folder.

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter at

The issue is that you trying to run Vaadin 24 application with container that does not support Serlet 5+ or newer. The javax.servlet should be now jakarta.servlet. You need to upgrade to Quarkus 3. Also you may have other dependencies you need to update.

Comment: Thanks!!I still have another problem

Comment: maven.compiler.source: 17
vaadin.version: 24.0.0
quarkus.version: 3.0.0.Alpha6

fixed the previous bug, now when npm install runs all node_modules are 
created in the project, but when mvn quarkus:dev runs it deletes me 
the node_modules folder.

Answer (score -1):

```
maven.compiler.source: 17
vaadin.version: 24.0.0
quarkus.version: 3.0.0.Alpha6
```

I fixed the previous bug, now when npm install runs all node_modules are created in the project, but when mvn quarkus:dev runs, it deletes the node_modules folder.